# order two names in alphabetical order

Tags: c, char

I've got an essay where is says "Given name and number of votes of two candidates, make two charts which one is sorted by the number of votes increasing, and the other in alphabetical order."

I've done the first part of the code already, and it's something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    char candidato1[50], candidato2[50];
    int voti1, voti2;
    
    scanf("%s", &candidato1);
    scanf("%s", &voti1);
    
    printf("Ordine basato sul numero di voti in verso cresciente\n");
    printf("%-10s %-10s\n", "Nome" "Numero di voti",);
    if (voti1>voti2) {
        printf("%-10s %-10d\n", candidato1, voti1);
        printf("%-10s %-10d\n", candidato2, voti2);
    }else {
    printf("%-10s %-10d\n", candidato2, voti2);
    printf("%-10s %-10d\n", candidato1, voti1);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("Ordine alfabetico\n");
    printf("%-10s %-10s\n", "Nome" "Numero di voti",);

    //alphabetical order here
    return 0;
}
```

As I've said in my previous post, I'm still new to c, and char are really a mystery for me. I've did some searches online but I couldn't find anything useful or clearly understandable for me. Hope someone here can help me figure it out.

Comment: The assignment probably expects you to use the [`strcmp()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html) function to determine how to order the candidates by name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `strcmp` function from `string.h` to compare strings in alphabetic manner. If it returns number > 0 than first string is greater then second, similarly, if it returns number < 0 than second string is greater then first, otherwise if it returns 0 than the strings are equal.

It would look like that:

```
if (strcmp(candidato1, candidato2) > 0) {
    printf("%-10s %-10d\n", candidato1, voti1);
    printf("%-10s %-10d\n", candidato2, voti2);
} else {
    printf("%-10s %-10d\n", candidato2, voti2);
    printf("%-10s %-10d\n", candidato1, voti1);
}
```

Do not forget to `#include <string.h>`

Comment: That did the trick, thank you! also don't worry if you noticed any type errors and missing strings in the code I've posted, I've eventually find them out and now it works!